# How to check if the value in the mySQL DB exist?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a mySQL database and I have a Perl script that connects to it and performs some data manipulation.
One of the tables in the DB looks like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE `mydb`.`companies` (
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`) );
```

I want to insert some data in this table. The problem is that some companies in the data can be repeated.

The question is: How do I check that the "company_name" already exist? If it exist I need to retrieve "company_id" and use it to insert the data into another table. If it does not, then this info should be entered in this table, but I already have this code.

Here is some additional requirement: The script can be run multiple times simultaneously, so I can't just read the data into the hash and check if it already exist.

I can throw an additional "SELECT" query, but it will create an additional hit on the DB.

I tried to look for an answer, but every question here or the thread on the web talks about using the primary key checking. I don't need this. The DB structure is already set but I can make changes if need to be. This table will be used as an additional table.

Is there another way? In both DB and Perl.

Comment: The company name should be part of the primary key, you wouldn't have a problem if you did that.

Comment: Good point, Mat. I added that as option 2 in my answer.

Comment: @Mat: "company_id" is a foreign key in another table. If I make the primary key with 2 fields than the table won't be needed. However it will break database normalization. I know that it's not a dogma, but being a good developer I want to follow those rules. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It would help if we saw your exact workflow.  From your question and some of your comments its not clear exactly where you need improvement, only that you're concerned about one extra SELECT.  (Do you just need `$dbh->{mysql_insertid}` ?)

Comment: @pilcrow OK, I have another table called investments with the structure: CREATE TABLE investments(investment_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, company_id INT, investor_id INT, ....); investments table has a foreign key "company_id". What I need is to insert the data in the "companies" table with unique names so that "investments" table can have appropriate foreign key value. I'm trying to see if there is an easy solution without hitting the DB more than needs to be.

Comment: I need first to check if the record exist in the companies table. If it does retrieve the id of the existing company name. If not add the record and get the last id. Then insert the record in the investments table using the retrieved company id. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The script can be run multiple times simultaneously, so I can't just read the data into the hash and check if it already exist."

It sounds like your biggest concern is that one instance of the script may insert a new company name while another script is running. The two scripts may check the DB for the existence of that company name when it doesn't exist, and then they might both insert the data, resulting in a duplicate.

1. Assuming I'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to look at transactions. You need to be able to check for the data and insert the data before anyone else is allowed to check for that data. That will keep a second instance of the script from checking for data until the 1st instance is done checking AND inserting.

   Check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

   And: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html

   MyISAM doesn't support transactions. InnoDB does. So you need to make sure your table is InnoDB. Start your set of queries with `START TRANSACTION`.
2. Alternatively, you could do this, if you have a unique index on company_name (which you should).

   ```
   $query_string = "INSERT INTO `companies` (NULL,'$company_name')";
   ```

   This will result in an error if the `company_name` already exists. Try a sample run attempting to insert a duplicate company name. In PHP,

   ```
   $result = mysql_query($query_string);
   ```

   $result will equal false on error.  So,

   ```
   if(!$result) {
     $query2 = "INSERT INTO `other_table` (NULL,`$company_name`)";
     $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
   }
   ```

   If you have a unique key on company_name in both tables, then MySQL will not allow you to insert duplicates. Your multiple scripts may spend a lot of time trying to insert duplicates, but they will not succeed.

EDIT: continuing from the above code, and doing your work for you, here is what you would do if the insert was successful.

```
if(!$result) {
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO `other_table` (NULL,`$company_name`)";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
} else if($result !== false) { // must use '!==' rather than '!=' because of loose PHP typing
  $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
  $query2 = "UPDATE `other_table` SET `some_column` = 'some_value' WHERE `id` = '$last_id'";
  // OR, maybe you want this query
  // $query2a = "INSERT INTO `other_table` (`id`,`foreign_key_id`) VALUES (NULL,'$last_id');
}
```

Comment: 1. I am working with DB doing couple of inserts in one transaction. Basically I'm inserting data in couple tables inside one transaction (7 or 8 tables) but only 3 needs to be checked checked for the duplicates inside this big transaction. 2. As I said to Mat I can't make it part of primary key, I can only set it to be unique. Any other idea? Thank you.

Comment: Well, solution #2 means that I will hit the DB twice: once on insert and then on select to retrieve the id (primary key). This is not very sufficient. Also the table will grow up with time and the load on the DB will be huge.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to get the id of the inserted value for use in the other tables? This might seem incredible, but that actually does not require a 2nd db hit. Let me know if this is what you mean and I will add it to my answer.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. I mean I will access the table twice in a row, right?

Comment: Well then you are wrong, because you can use mysql_insert_id() to get the id of the last inserted value and you can then use that in your next query. See my edit. And by the way, if I've solved your problem, do give me the check mark, will you? Or else let me know what else you need to know.

Comment: Well, I'm already using transactions. My problem is that I have a bulk of data that I need to insert in one transaction and during this bulk insert I need this check. Is nested transactions supported by mySQL/Perl? Or I can safely do: [pseudo-code] start transaction; insert; insert; insert; if error get the id; else get last inserted id; insert; insert; commit transaction[end-pseudocode]?

Comment: The idea of the transaction is that if it fails at any point, the database is reverted to its pre-transaction state. I'm not sure about nested transactions, though. But can't you try the above code and see if it works? You can make a copy of your database structure into a test database, enter in a few test values, and test it. Your problem really seems to be you're not trying any potential solutions out. Search "perl mysql last insert id". Check out this from mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: That's right, you don't pay for it. Hopefully this will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a stored procedure(STP), which takes input as company name. 
In this STP, first check existing company name. If it exists, return id. Otherwise, insert and return id.

This way, you hit DB only once

Comment: Yes, but no guarantee of avoiding duplicate inserts with 2 instances of the script running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB use transaction. For MyISAM lock table, do modifications, unlock.